# Faking http-host headers with pytest (and potential security issues)?

Tags: python, django, security, http-headers, pytest

I am running a django app with a REST API and I am protecting my API endpoint with a custom permission. It looks like this:

```
class MyPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        host = request.META.get('HTTP_HOST', None)
        return host == "myhost.de"
        )
```

The idea is that my API is only accessible via "myhost.de".

Right now I am testing this with pytest. I can set my headers with:

```
 @pytest.fixture()
    def request_unauth(self, client):
        result = client.get(
            "myurl",
            headers={'HTTP_HOST', 'myhost.de'},
            content_type="application/json",
        )
        return result

   def test_host(request_unauth):
     assert request_unauth.status_code == 200
```

Since I can easily fake my headers I assume that this might also be easily done with other tools? How can `MyPermission` be evaluated from a security perspective?

Thanks so much for any help and hints. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I figured out the first part: I can just do `{"HTTP_HOST", "myhost"}`. I'll update my question

Comment: You might want to test that with `https` (instead of `http`), as the SSL certificate might protect you because of the mismatching host header with the certificate.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you! Do you think I should then also do `request.META.get('HTTPS_HOST', None)` in my permission?

Comment: What is the purpose of this protection? What is the threat that this is supposed to mitigate?

Comment: @GaborLengyel Let's say I want the frontend of my website be able to access my API data. I also want to allow users to visit my website and access the data. But I don't want anyone to access my data with a bot or with any other tools to hit my database

Comment: And how would this help with that? The bot would also send `Host: myhost.de`. I mean, that's not even hacking, just by sending the request to your API, a browser will automatically include the correct `Host` header.

Comment: I thought the HTTP_HOST would automatically be the domain name where the request is coming from?

Comment: Host is the target name by which the web server selects virtual hosts. What I think you mean is the `Origin` and `Referer` headers, but what you would like to achieve is still not possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the `Host` header like that does not make sense, and will not protect against 3rd party clients as you described in comments. An attacker can create an arbitrary client and send request to your API, and that request can (and will) include the correct `Host` header as any other legitimate request.

Also based on your comments, you want to authenticate the client application, which is not technically possible, as it has been discussed many times. With some work (the amount of which you can influence somewhat) anybody can create a different client to your API, and there is no secure way you could prevent that, because anything you include in your client will be known to users (attackers), and will allow them to copy it. You can and probably should authenticate your users though, check access patterns, implement rate limiting, revoke user access in case of suspicious activity and so on - but this is all based on user authentication.

You can also prevent access from a client running in a standard browser on different domain, by sending the correct CORS headers (or not sending CORS headers at all) in your API.